# How to take count of no of files in hdfs directory

Tags: scala, apache-spark, hdfs

Hi I'm using below code to list out no files from  hdfs directory .
Now I have to count no of files I got from list  using below code but getting error.

[image: Error]

```scala
val hdfspath = "/data/fnl-ecomm/release/*/*/*/schema/*.json" import org.apache.hadoop.fs. (FileSystem, Path)

val fs = org.apache.hadoop.fs.FileSystem.get(spark.sparkContext.hadoopConfiguration)

fs.globStatus(new Path(hdfspath)).filter(.isFile).map(_.getPath).foreach(println)

var count: Int =0
 
if(status!=null)

while(status.hasNext)

{

status.next
 count += 1

} print("Count is", count)

}

else

{

print("count is zero")
}
```

I have tried above code but getting error

Comment: Please avoid adding images, code snippets are much better.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
import org.apache.hadoop.fs.FileSystem

val fs = FileSystem.get(spark.sparkContext.hadoopConfiguration)
val filesCount = fs.listStatus(new Path(hdfsPath)).count(_.isFile)
```